# Map Depth to RGB Space

Tags: java, processing, kinect

I'm using the KinectPV2 library which is great but very poorly documented.

With reference to the example "MapDepthToColor" copied below I'm trying to retrieve the depth for each RGB pixel.

Having managed to tweak the original example to map the Depth to RGB space I'm left with a strange duplicated edge (see bottom left image).

Can someone point out what's going on?

```
/*
Thomas Sanchez Lengeling.
<a href="http://codigogenerativo.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://codigogenerativo.com/</a>

KinectPV2, Kinect for Windows v2 library for processing

Color to fepth Example,
Color Frame is aligned to the depth frame
*/

import KinectPV2.*;

KinectPV2 kinect;

int [] depthZero;

//BUFFER ARRAY TO CLEAN DE PIXLES
PImage depthToColorImg;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 848, P3D);

  depthToColorImg = createImage(512, 424, PImage.RGB);
  depthZero    = new int[ KinectPV2.WIDTHDepth * KinectPV2.HEIGHTDepth];

  //SET THE ARRAY TO 0s
  for (int i = 0; i < KinectPV2.WIDTHDepth; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < KinectPV2.HEIGHTDepth; j++) {
      depthZero[424*i + j] = 0;
    }
  }

  kinect = new KinectPV2(this);
  kinect.enableDepthImg(true);
  kinect.enableColorImg(true);
  kinect.enablePointCloud(true);

  kinect.init();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  float [] mapDCT = kinect.getMapDepthToColor(); // Size: 434,176 (512*424)

  //get the raw data from depth and color
  int [] colorRaw = kinect.getRawColor(); // Size: 2,073,600 (1920*1080)

  int [] depthRaw = kinect.getRawDepthData(); // 434176

  //clean de pixels
  PApplet.arrayCopy(depthZero, depthToColorImg.pixels);

  int count = 0;
  depthToColorImg.loadPixels();
  for (int i = 0; i < KinectPV2.WIDTHDepth; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < KinectPV2.HEIGHTDepth; j++) {

      //incoming pixels 512 x 424 with position in 1920 x 1080
      float valX = mapDCT[count * 2 + 0];
      float valY = mapDCT[count * 2 + 1];


      //maps the pixels to 512 x 424, not necessary but looks better
      int valXDepth = (int)((valX/1920.0) * 512.0);
      int valYDepth = (int)((valY/1080.0) * 424.0);

      int  valXColor = (int)(valX);
      int  valYColor = (int)(valY);

      if ( valXDepth >= 0 && valXDepth < 512 && valYDepth >= 0 && valYDepth < 424 &&
        valXColor >= 0 && valXColor < 1920 && valYColor >= 0 && valYColor < 1080) {
        float col = map(depthRaw[valYDepth * 512 + valXDepth], 0, 4500, 0, 255);
        //color colorPixel = colorRaw[valYColor * 1920 + valXColor]; // This works as intended
        color colorPixel = color(col); // This doesn't
        depthToColorImg.pixels[valYDepth * 512 + valXDepth] = colorPixel;
      } 
      count++;
    }
  }
  depthToColorImg.updatePixels();

  image(depthToColorImg, 0, 424);
  image(kinect.getColorImage(), 0, 0, 512, 424);
  image(kinect.getDepthImage(), 512, 0);

  text("fps: "+frameRate, 50, 50);
}
```

[image: Current faulty result]

Comment: I'm not familiar witht he library so can only offer a few guesses: It's possible You're iterating in such a way that you missed those pixels (due to rounding errors). Also, I think there's some confusion about the word "depth". In some places, you appear to use it to mean width:  `valXDepth < 512`  and in other cases, it means distance from kinext  `int [] depthRaw = kinect.getRawDepthData();`.  Try changing the inside for you `if ( valXDepth >= 0 && ...` block to ignore the depth data and just output a solid color. If the issue is with the data, you'll get a solid colour image back..

Comment: ... If, on the other hand, it's a problem with how you're iterating, the output should have the same bands.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "ignore depth data"? Most of the code above is taken from an example, thus I'm still unsure as to what `kinect.getMapDepthToColor()` returns exactly. I've slightly tweaked the code above in the hope to further illustrate the problem. When the color is assigned using `colorRaw[]` then it works as intented, unlike `depthRaw[]` which causes dup effect.

Comment: The issue is that `colorRaw[]` and `depthRaw[]` are in a different scale. The result seems very close but I'm stuck to solve this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant as a sanity check... Remove everything inside your `if` statement and replace it with ... `depthToColorImg.pixels[valYDepth * 512 + valXDepth] = Color.Red;` or similar. Then run your code and verify that the output image is a solid colour. The purpose was to confirm that it's not a positioning/rounding error, but it looks like you've already eliminated that possibility. Sorry I can't help further without a kinect.

Comment: Here's an update on this issue - `kinect.getMapDepthToColor()` returns the index of the color pixel mapped to the space and scale of the depth image.

Therefore, what I'm trying to do is actually the opposite - to get the depth value mapped the space and scale of the color image.

Is there a way to reverse the logic of `kinect.getMapDepthToColor()` to achieve this?

Comment: I do not own a kinect, but I've watched this playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmVNgdapJJM&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZMlWHdcy8hAGDy6IaoxUKf maybe it can help you

Answer (score 0):

I posted the solution to this issues here: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/comment/95494#Comment_95494